# Output array so it can be used as value for data attribute

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array in PHP that I am looping through to get content.

When echoed, the results of my array variable `$myArray` looks like the below

```
Array(
  [0] => ABC
  [1] => DEF
  [2] => GHI
  [3] => JKL
     )
Array(
  [0] => MNO
  [1] => 123A
  [2] => 123B
  [3] => 123C
     )
Array(
  [0] => orange
  [1] => yellow
  [2] => green
  [3] => blue
     )
```

But when i pass this to the html data element using

```
data-results = "$myArray"
```

I get a

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

error.

How can this be passed as one array to the html data element?

Answer (score 6):

I think , you may use the below code . It will work incase if array values having special characters .

```
<div data-results="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($myArray), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print your array into a string equivalent, you can use:

```
$stringArray = print_r($array, true);
echo $stringArray;
```

If you wish to print it as a JSON string, you can use:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: The data is being pulled dynamically so how can i change it in your second solution?

Comment: Just use `data-results="<?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>"`.

Comment: Like @localheinz said, just use a PHP block and echo your array with the json_encode function. That should do the trick.

Comment: @jumpman8947 you can also have into account encoding issues. If your JSON data happens to have special characters you might want to check the additional parameters of the json_encode function.

Answer (score 0):

This has probably already been answered elsewhere, but you cannot echo an array out.  You can only echo out a scalar value or an object that has a `__toString()` method on it.

So it's `data-results="{$myArray[0][0]}"` or something else in your case, since you have a multi-dimensional array.  What you probably want is some sort of for loop:

```
foreach ($myArray as $arr) {
   foreach ($arr as $value) {
        echo "data-rule={$value}";
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not directly echoing my array. I was just telling you that was in the array. I am using the html data-element in a button which will save the content to be later displayed when the button is pressed.

Comment: Will this work if i want to pass the first set of data in the first array (ABC, DEF,GHI,JKL) to be displayed when i click the button?